# How does Qt's model/view implementation work in the background?

Tags: qt

I want to find some information about Model/View's implementation, but it's not documented.

By the way, I don't want information about how to use Model/View, what I want to know is its procedures, such as which function is called when, etc.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Are you asking about how Qt's model/view implementation works in the background?

Comment: yeah!  you are right .. i don't know how to express it ..:-D  thank you...

Comment: Use the source, Luke. I think that's the best bet if you want to learn about implementation details instead of how to use the API.

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld: how to debug the source? thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigate this yourself. You can

- look at the source code
- use an interactive debugger
- write some code to try to intercept the signals and slots (I believe there's something built into Designer)
- use a Qt-specific tool to look at the live objects like [Qt Inspector](https://github.com/robertknight/Qt-Inspector)

Comment: For a possibly nicer way to browse around the source code, check out this: http://code.woboq.org/kde/qt4/src/gui/itemviews/qstandarditemmodel.cpp.html#_ZNK18QStandardItemModel4dataERK11QModelIndexi (Hover over the symbols..)

Answer (score 1):

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/model-view-programming.html

Comment: yeah! thanks for your answer, this passage just talk about the structure and how to use it, i want to find some Principle, and the procedure it display.. ^_^

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.  I don't understand what you want.

Comment: for example: i have a class MyModel  inherit from QAbstractItemModel, i must implement tree function, and we know there is function named data(), and who will call it,, and so no...in a word, when we call view.show(), then the procedure how it work by funtion...i think it's something about source code..dose it clear?  can you help me ?

Comment: Answers should not be just a link. Please expand this.